# Amazon S3 Rest API Integration Error

Tags: rest-api, amazon-aws

I am new to AWS. I am sending attachment data from Salesforce to AWS S3 using Rest API. But it is giving following error : The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

I could not find any reference for generating version 4 signature. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/92cf05807ac4becbd21f

Comment: AWS v4 signature is going to be supported in Summer '19 (live in mid-June) out of the box via Named Credentials: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_define.htm&type=5

Comment: I have tried using Named Credentials but it is giving below error 'The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method'. Tried everything but no luck. @identigral

Comment: @GauravChauhan Open a support case with SF, they should be able to debug this.

Comment: Thanks @identigral finally I was able to perform integration with AWS S3 using version 4 signature and named credentials that you had suggested.